# I want to rtrim a bullet entity but an 8 is also trimmed. Why?

Tags: php

Check out this code.

```
$bt = "abc8 &#8226; ";
echo $bt . "<P>";
$bt = rtrim($bt," &#8226; ");
echo $bt . "<P>";

$bt = "abc7 &#8226; ";
echo $bt . "<P>";
$bt = rtrim($bt," &#8226; ");
echo $bt . "<P>";
```

On my server, running PHP7.2, this returns,

> abc8 •
>
> abc
>
> abc7 •
>
> abc7

Why is the "8" being dropped in the first pair???

If I use the actual bullet symbol in the code, rather than the 8226 entity, it works fine.

Comment: because you've listed "8" as one of the characters to be stripped. PHP is seeing what you put in the second argument to rtrim as a list of individual characters. It will find **all** references to each of those separate characters and remove them. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: So the answer is that I'm a dummy! Ha-ha! Sorry to waste your time, everyone. I usually remember to check the docs first. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of `rtrim()`. From [the documentation](http://php.net/rtrim):

> You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list **all characters that you want to be stripped**.

Regular expression or a simple `str_replace()` would be what you're looking for.

```
$bt = str_replace(" &#8226; ", "", $bt);

$bt = preg_replace("/\s*&#8226;\s*$/", "", $bt);
```